# How to use set line number in file along with vim command

Tags: linux, vim

I know the typical method to set line number in file using `set number`, however i want to use this as while opening the file. something like this
`vim filename ******`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass arbitrary commands to vim with `+`.

```
$ vim somefile.txt '+set number'
```

See the [`vim` man page](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/vim1.html).

However, customizations like this usually go in your `~/.vimrc` file:

```
set number
```